# Turbo c++ colour codes

Tags: c++, graphics, colors, turbo-c++, turbo-c

I have been using turbo c++ from quite long time, I have noticed that there are by default 16 colours(0-15) but I know that there is a way to make your own custom background and text colours, does anybody know how to do it...?

Comment: Ditch Turbo C++ and use some post-first-standard C++ compiler, like g++/clang++ etc, with a text editor or IDE.

Comment: You guys just don't appreciate time-travel.

Comment: This really is unrelated to the compiler version.  It's about a particular graphics API... knowing more about the environment is necessary.  Is this DOS on a PC-AT compatible?

Comment: @BenVoigt I think it is DOS

Comment: @Martin James ,@vsoftco, There is an extension for graphics.h to be used with codeblocks, so turbo c++ is an ancient relic, but library isn't...!

Answer (score 1):

In text mode there truly are only 16 colors each for foreground and background, because foreground and background color are each specified by a four bit bitfield, so that the total is 8 bits, and it's stored in video RAM just like that and interpreted by the GPU (in VESA emulation mode).

To get additional colors, you'll have to switch to a graphics mode.  You may want to search for "Turbo C++ graphic mode", which finds many tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

In Turbo C++ you can use `textcolor( )`    `textbackground( )` to set whatever color you want out of the color palette. Browse the Help menu.

```
// MSDOS Turbo C++ code
#include <conio.h> 


    int main() 
    { 

        textbackground(BLUE); //set the background color 
        textcolor(WHITE); 
        clrscr();
        gotoxy(30,12); 
        cputs("Hello"); 


    return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, I know that there are 16 macros/enumerator for default colour,but I want more than 16 colours.

Answer (score -1):

You *can* use more colors using graphics by using `setrgbpalette()` function... To know more about this function see `setrgbpalette` in the help index (or [here](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setrgbpalette.html)) and compile the given example of `setrgbpalette`. You can create more custom colors, but only 16 colors can be used at a time.